# navigationTitle not showing up when navigating from target view

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I have three views in my SwiftUI project. I navigate through these views as such: `LoginView` > `TabMenuView` > `TemplateView`.

In TemplateView, the .navigationTitle and .toolbar does not show up when using the above. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? When I start from `TabMenuView`, and then navigate to `TemplateView` it does show up.

```
struct LoginView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = AuthViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                Color.backgroundcolor.ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                VStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        viewModel.loginUser()
                    }) {
                        Text("Login")
                    }
                    .navigationDestination(isPresented: $viewModel.isLoggedIn) {
                        TabMenuView()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct TabMenuView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationStack {
                TemplateView(viewModel: TemplateViewViewModel())
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("Workout", systemImage: "flame")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct TemplateView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = TemplateViewViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(.backgroundcolor).ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            
            VStack {
                Text("This is my view.")
            }
            .navigationTitle("Templates")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                    NavigationLink(destination: AddTemplate()) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                            .foregroundColor(.accent)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to embed `TemplateView` in a `NavigationStack`. I have also tried to apply the navigation